# Multiline textbox does not display properly in Crystal Report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a multiline textbox saving into database as data type text. When trying to print it out on crystal report, the format is always off whenever I use tab within the textbox. Is there a way to counter this?

[image: Example data key into multiline text box]

[image: Example data display at Crystal report]

Comment: Your explanation is too vague.  Assume that we have no prior knowledge of your project... because we have no prior knowledge of your project.  How are we supposed to know what "the format is always off" is supposed to mean unless your provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation?  Assume that too many words is better than not enough. You can also provide a screenshot if it helps illustrate the issue. Also, you should be providing an example that we can use to reproduce the issue. Obviously you can't post a report but an example of the data that produces the issue would be a good start.

Comment: sorry about that, added image to explain the situation